# How can I raise and event from within angular that can be seen by code outside of angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm sorry if this question is light on code specifics, but I'm really just looking for a pattern here.

I've got a web page that has a component built in angularjs, call it A, and a component built using plain old native JavaScript, call it B.  Users can do interactive stuff with A and B and that all works just fine.  The problem is that there is a third component, C, written in native JavaScript that is responsible for saving the state of the entire page for the user, i.e. a combined set of states from A and B.  So, to do this calculated values, not just HTML element values that I could write jQuery for, have to come out of A and find their way to C.

Handling B is easy because I can use callbacks or events or whatever to have B pass its data to C.  I've been struggling hard, however, to do a similar thing with A.  I've tried injecting C into A but then C can't see B.  I've also tried to create a custom event that A can fire off to the "outside world" using $rootScope.$emit() but that hasn't worked either, which is too bad because I'd prefer an event-based approach.

This doesn't seem like an extraordinary scenario to me so I'm surprised that I haven't found any discussions of a pattern around it.  Everything I find seems to talk about getting stuff into angular, not out.  Am I just thinking about all this the wrong way?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. If C is plain JS then instantiate C using Angularjs and pass the data from A to a Service that The wrapper or C can pick and pass to C. I think it would make more sense to wrap your plain JS in an angular controller/service.

Comment: If it has to be event based, look for pub/sub libraries. Numerous ones available. Unfortunately will be expensive having to add a lot of angular watches though